# Make a specific bulk upsert using SQLAlchemy (MariaDB)

Tags: python, mysql, merge, sqlalchemy, upsert

From a list of Item objects like so :

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    item_id = Column(Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True,)
    price = Column(Integer(10))
    updated_at = Column(Numeric(30))
    ...
```

How can I upsert data into the MariaDB database using Python to refresh the data of the items using a fast solution, preferably bulk insert or similar?

I did try using the `merge()` function, but it takes way too much time, especially since I have a dataset of 30k objects to refresh once every x hours.

I also tried the `add_all()`, it does work really fast but is erroring when it encounters an existing primary_key (item_id).

Answer (score 0):

Probably want to use insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert. I'm not sure if you have the 30K objects already in the app or you are loading them and altering them.  Probably fastest to use core but it seems like in 2+ (maybe 1.4+) you can mix them a bit.

[orm-upsert-statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-upsert-statements)

[insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert)

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. The data is already in the DB and has to be entirely updated every set of hours. I did try your solution, it works individually, but in a batch it takes two hours for 25MB of data, which seems off, but I guess it has to go back & forth between the server and the DB to process the lines one by one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  "UPSERT" means you insert if it is not in the DB or update if it is.  But you mean the data is always in the db so you are always doing an update?